# Github pages HashRouter not displaying components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router, github-pages

My react app on github page doesn't render the components using HashRouter, blank page on "/" and 404 error  on "/about".
this is my app.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Container-fluid" id="div2">
      <HashRouter basename="/Landing-Page">
        <Header />

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/thankyou" element={<ThankYou />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            element={
              <div className="Container">
                <SignUp validate={validate} />
                <EbookInfo />
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        </Routes>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

on homepage it shows `.../Landing-Page/` as expected
but on other page it shows `.../about` instead of `.../Landing-Page/about`.
I have gh-pages setup.
my github page  https://alexhmar.github.io/Landing-Page/
my repo https://github.com/alexhmar/Landing-Page/tree/master

I have also tried this with `<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}` but it's the same issue.

Comment: Sure you` logged in` correctly? Eventually `404 error` triggers while page does not exist and while you don't have access to this page

Comment: Can you add the `Header` component to your question so we can see how you are navigating? You might also need to specify a homepage in your package json file, though the `basename` prop on the router should take care of this.

Answer (score 4):

When using Github Pages and React Router Dom you need to use the [Hash Router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter).

Replace your import by `import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";` and it should work.

Github Pages isn't configured for single page applications, if you try to access /bar, it will try to find a `bar.html` file and thus give you a 404. By using the hash router, when you navigate to links it will go to `/#bar` so Github Pages won't redirect you and React Router Dom will see it as navigating to /bar as you'd expect it, as long as you're using the [Link component](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) or the hooks.

Comment: I tried HashRouter but now even the homepage is blank.Not a 404 error but it's just blank

Comment: @SaulLopez Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console, components don't appear on the root div

Answer (score -2):

I deployed on Heroku instead of Github pages,now it's working fine.